# Change this row and previous row vectorised in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe that encodes the last value of row 'this' in row 'last'. I want to match the column 'this' in the table according to value in a list, e.g. `['b', 'c']` and then change the preceding row's 'this', as well as this row's 'last' to the value 'd' on such a match.

For example, I want to change this:

| this | last |
| --- | --- |
| a |  |
| b | a |
| a | b |
| c | a |
| a | c |

Into this:

| this | last |
| --- | --- |
| d |  |
| b | d |
| d | b |
| c | d |
| a | c |

This is straightforward if iterating, but too slow:

```py
for i, v in df['this'].iteritems():
    if v in ['b', 'c']:
        df['this'].iloc[i - 1] = 'd'
        df['last'].iloc[i] = 'd'
```

I believe this can be done by assigning `df.this.shift(-1)` to column 'last', however I'm not sure how to do this when I'm matching values in the list `['b', 'c']`. How can I do this without iterating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df
   this last
0   a   NaN
1   b   a
2   a   b
3   c   a
4   a   c
```

You can use `isin` to get boolean index where the values belong to the list (`l1`). Then populate corresponding `last` with `d`. And then [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) in upward direction the boolean index, to populate required `this` values with d

```
l1 = ['b', 'c']
this_in_l1 = df['this'].isin(l1)
df.loc[this_in_l1, 'last'] = 'd'
df.loc[this_in_l1.shift(-1, fill_value=False), 'this'] = 'd'

df
  this last
0   d   NaN
1   b   d
2   d   b
3   c   d
4   a   c
```